# Applications of Burnside's Formula

Tags: group-theory

The applications of Burnside's formula in counting orbits has wide applications (I believe). But, whatever the books I followed on Group Theory, many (or almost all) of the applications mentioned in them are for "coloring problem" which involves roughly coloring vertices of a regular $n$-gon with different colors.

**Q.** What are the other simple applications of Burnsides theorem which I can present to undergraduates while teaching group theory?

Comment: Counting graphs up to isomorphism (but don't ask me for details).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16630/nice-application-of-the-cauchy-frobenius-burnside-p%C3%B3lya-formula

Comment: Here's a list of fifty [Burnside lemma and Pólya enumeration theorem examples](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13335/25554) from this site.

Comment: Thanks very much for useful link @Caranti.

Comment: @Groups, you're welcome!

Comment: I'd mention to your students this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4609764/1092170

Answer (score 1):

If you allow for Polya's enumeration theorem also here are a list of interesting problems that have been answered:

[How many ways can you put 8 red, 6 green and 7 blue balls in 4 indistinguishable bins?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099238/how-many-ways-can-you-put-8-red-6-green-and-7-blue-balls-in-4-indistinguishable) (A sweet solution by Marko Riedel)

[The classical problem of necklaces and braceletets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) . Also an [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766652/how-many-ways-can-we-place-two-types-of-balls-on-a-circle/1065569#1065569).

[Using it to count graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938519/how-many-directed-graphs-of-size-n-are-there-where-each-vertex-is-the-tail-of-ex/941551#941551) (An incredible solution by Marko Riedel)