# Any interesting application of Burnside's lemma?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I haven't found satisfying answer yet. Beside those typical examples *like how many colourings of a cube is there up to rotations* or *how many graphs are there on n vertices up to isomorphism* etc., is there any "real" usage of Burnside's lemma in advanced math? All examples I could find seem to me more like funny riddles you can impress your friends with but they are not quite useful for anything.

Comment: See: https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204_2018/Jenny_Jin_paper.pdf

Comment: Here is a result from "probabilistic graph theory." We say that a graph is "asymmetric" if the automorphism group of the graph is trivial. The probability that a randomly-chosen, connected graph with $n$ vertices is asymmetric approaches zero as $n$ approaches infinity. This result uses Burnside's Lemma, but the proof is a bit long for me to write down as an answer.

Comment: This argument uses the lemma to prove that, if $p\nmid q-1$, then $C_p$ acts trivially on $C_q$, *without* knowing anything about $\operatorname{Aut}(C_q)$ (not even its order, let alone its isomorphism class): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4609764/1092170